# Optaplanner max travel distance for vehicle

Tags: routes, optaplanner

I am trying to define the max travel distance limit and am not able to do the same. Would appreciate any help on defining the maximum travel distance for each vehicle. In case any packet is outside that distance limit and cannot be combined with other packet pickups, vehicle will directly go to pick that packet and bring it back to Depot.

Comment: _defining the maximum travel distance for each vehicle_ to go where?. please add some details to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and complete scenario is like, I have 10 different locations to pick the packets and to restrict the total travel distance of each vehicle. I have been able to accommodate the vehicle of different capacity. Each capacity vehicle should travel only as per their defined distance limits. In case any packet falls outside the limit, a separate vehicle should be sent to pick that packet.